# trying to find a solution for the following question

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

when running logstash.bat I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Logstash comes bundled with the recommended JDK(), but is
overridden by the version defined in LS_JAVA_HOME. Consider clearing
LS_JAVA_HOME to use the bundled JDK
```

Any idea how to solve this error?
Thank you in advance